# Validation Failed: cannot have more than 100 pull request via curl? [git bash]

Tags: github, automation, git-bash

So I'm trying to create pull requests via curl commands which have been working so far, however it seems that I've reached a limit as I'm getting the error message:

```
"message": "Validation Failed",
"errors": [
      "resource": "PullRequest"
      "code" : "custom"
      "message": "cannot have more than 100 pull requests with the same head_sha."
]
```

I've created about 350 pull requests so it could be because of that. Is there a work around? Thanks.

Comment: were you trying to submit all 350 pull requests at the same time?

Comment: well I was trying to test a feature and I realised the problem was I was pull requesting the same commit over an over again, hence why github didn't like it. I comitted some new changes and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can also create those PRs from the [GitHub CLI tool](https://github.com/cli/cli): [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create)

```
gh pr create --title "Pull request title" --body "Pull request body"
```

Second, that will also allow you to *close* a PR when you are done: [`gh pr close`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_close)

I would test if you still have that limit when you start closing your current PRs.

Comment: thanks for this, yea I realised the problem was I was pull requesting the same commit over an over again, hence why github didn't like it. I comitted some new changes and it worked fine.